# Create dataframe with space separated data using PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark

How can I create a dataframe for space separated columns?

DataType

```
yyyy  mm   tmax    tmin      af    rain     sun
1853   1    ---     ---     ---    57.3     ---
1853   2    ---     ---     ---    32.3     ---
1853   3    ---     ---     ---    65.5     ---
1853   4    ---     ---     ---    46.2     ---
1853   5    ---     ---     ---    13.2     ---
1853   6    ---     ---     ---    53.3     ---
1853   7    ---     ---     ---    78.0     ---
1853   8    ---     ---     ---    56.6     ---
1853   9    ---     ---     ---    24.5     ---
1853  10    ---     ---     ---    94.8     ---
1853  11    ---     ---     ---    75.5     ---
```

Comment: where is this data, in .txt or csv ?

Comment: data in txt format and there is also space before yyyy.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have put `pyspark` as tag (and not `pandas`), you could try something like that:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Space Import Test').getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv('/path/to/your/file',inferSchema=True,header=True,sep=' ',ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace=True)
df.show(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas` and add the  `delim_whitespace` argument to `True`

> delim_whitespace : boolean, default False
>
> Specifies whether or not whitespace (e.g. ' ' or '\t') will be used as the sep. Equivalent to setting sep='\s+'. If this option is
>   set to True, nothing should be passed in for the delimiter parameter.
>   *source: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html*

In your case:

```
import pandas

pandas.read_csv("data.txt", delim_whitespace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd   
data = pd.read_csv('text.txt', sep=" ") ## Sep is space as it your .txt file it is separated by space
data = data.dropna(axis=1, how='all') ## Since you have space before 1st column, we have to drop NA's created by space
```